# Orlicz space property for locally compact discrete group $G$

Tags: measure-theory, orlicz-spaces

A function $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to[0,\infty]$ is called a Young function if $\varphi $ is convex, even,and left continuous with  $\varphi(0)=0 $, also let $G$ denote a locally compact group with a left Haar measure $\lambda$. and $$M^{\varphi}(G)=\{f :G\to \mathbb{C}: f\;\text{is measurable },\;\int_G \varphi(a|f(x)|) \,\mathrm d\lambda(x)<\infty\; \;\text{for all }a>0\}$$
I want to prove the following lemma

> **Lemma**Let $\varphi$be a strictly increasing, continuous Young function the following statements are equivalent

> 1. $M^{\varphi}(G)\subseteq L^{\infty}(G)$

> 2.$G$ is discrete

**My Solution:**

I've done a proof for  $2\to1:$

$1\to2:$  Suppose $G$ is not discrete. Then there exist a relatively  compact neighborhood $K$ and a sequence $(K_n)$ of pairwise disjoint open subset of $K$ such that $$\lambda(K_n)\varphi(n^2)<\lambda(K)n^{-2}$$ for all $n\geq1.$ Define the function $f$ on $G$ by $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\chi_{K_n}(x)$$
but I have a problem to prove $f\in M^{\varphi}(G)$ and $\lambda(K_n)\varphi(n^2)<\lambda(K)n^{-2}$

Any idea or hint for a reference is welcome!